# java - recursive program for judging the validity of expression syntax (beginner)

Tags: java, recursion

I'm just learning java, and I have an assignment where I have to write a program that checks the validity of expressions about sets. Valid expressions are capital letters, an expression with a tilde in front, and can be combined using + and x as well as with parentheses. I've written a program that almost works, but I can't figure out how to get the binary operators to work with the parentheses.

It may also be that I have approached the problem in the wrong way (trying to validate from left to right, ignoring everything to the left once it's been validated). I can use any help I can get about writing recursive programs for this sort of problem; that is, if you have any pointers for a better way of approaching the problem, that would be incredibly helpful.

For reference, here is the code that I have:

```
public static boolean check(String expr) {       
         char spot;
         int close=0;
         expr = expr.trim();

  //base case
     if (expr.length() == 1 && expr.charAt(0)>= 'A' && expr.charAt(0) <= 'Z')
        return true;

        if (expr.charAt(0) == '~') {
            if (expr.charAt(1) == 'x' || expr.charAt(1) == '+' || expr.charAt(1) == ')')
                return false;
        return check(expr.substring(1));
        }


        if (expr.indexOf('x') > 0 && expr.indexOf('x') > expr.indexOf(')')) {
            int x = expr.indexOf('x');
            if (check(expr.substring(0, x)) && check(expr.substring(x)))
                return true;
        }

        if (expr.indexOf('+') > 0 && expr.indexOf('+') > expr.indexOf(')')) {
            int plus = expr.indexOf('+');
            if (check(expr.substring(0, plus)) && check(expr.substring(plus+1)))
                return true;
        }

        if (expr.charAt(0) == '(') {
        close = findEnd(expr.substring(1));
        if (close < 0)
           return false;
        if (check(expr.substring(1,close)) && check(expr.substring(close+1)))
           return true; 
     }      

     return false;

  }
```

Comment: I suggest you find a parser library in Java and use that rather than trying to do it all with indexOf/substring/regexes which is very prone to error and hard to reason about.

Comment: unfortunately we haven't learned how to use those yet, and so i think i'd only hurt myself on the assignment if i tried to figure that out! thank you though!

Comment: I don't see where this is recursive. That might be your first problem.

Comment: @user2313504 Can you more clearly explain what the grammar of 'expressions about sets' is? I don't understand it from your explanation.

Comment: Question: What is check(String)? PLEASE POST ALL RELEVANT CODES

Comment: @RyanStewart and @BlackMaggie: Looks like `check()` should be `valid()`.

Comment: whoops, you're right -- i started over so i copied/pasted without the class description and rewrote it wrong - fixed now

Comment: I think this is a class assignment or a least a learning exercise, so OP wants to write it themselves rather than using someone else's library. I think OP is looking for a "recursive descent" parser, but without more information about the class and the assignment, I can't be sure.

Comment: That's definitely what he wants, but I think he's supposed to implement it himself

Comment: @Patashu examples of valid/invalid expressions are probably the best way to explain: valid: A ~A (A+B)x(~(C+D)) invalid ~ A~B etc

Comment: yep - it's for an intro java class, and i have to write it myself with pretty much just recursion on the same method. prof says you should be able to do it with one or two recursive methods

Comment: other valid examples include: (A + B)x(~(J)xP)  and  ~(B+C+J)+(T x B)

Comment: OK, I just want to say: it's reasonable to point OP to resources and describe techniques, but please don't do their homework for them here. (Tempting as it is -- I really love writing parsers.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code is that complex. Recursion for this is pretty simple overall; here's what I'd do:

```
public static boolean check(String str) {
    if(str.equals("")) return true;
    if(str.charAt(0).isAlphaNumeric() || str.charAt(0) == '(' || str.charAt(0) == ')') return check(str.substring(1));
    return false;
}
```

Your edge cases are if the string is empty; if this is the case, then the string is valid. If the character doesn't match what you're looking for, return false. Otherwise, check the next character.

Comment: i'm not sure that this would work for cases like ~(B+C+J)+(T x B) and (A + B)x(~(J)xP)

Comment: @user2313504 This is a best-guess post. I have no idea what you're actually looking for. You can add more acceptable cases, too, if you'd like.